# Where to find "Photo" storage on my mac?

Tags: mac

I don't have any photos on my computer and I don't use iTunes or any other apple device, and yet my disk usage indicates that Photos is taking up 7GB of space.  Any idea where this is coming from and how I can clear it out?

[image]

Comment: Don't you have 7.06 GB of JPGs, PNGs, TIFFs, GIFs, etc. scattered on your disk?

Comment: The value reported may be based on all image extensions found on the drive, not necessarily one "Photos" folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a series of photos hidden away somewhere on your disk, or just want to find out whats taking up so much room on your mac, you can use a tool such as JDiskReport to scan it. It will return a directory listing that you can navigate through, showing which folders are taking up the most room.